# jQuery how to add blank option after a valuable option in select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

jQuery how to add blank option after a valuable option?

I wrote code but it add blank option at top of the dropdown. But I need one valuable option, one blank

like this:

```
<option></option>
<opton valu2="1">Red</option>
<option></option>
<option value="2">Green</option>
```

Here is my code:

```
<select id="theSelectId">
      <option selected="selected" value=""/>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    $("<option>", { value: '', selected: true }).prependTo("#theSelectId");​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Do you an example of what you want the output to be?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have several unprintable characters after the JS code:

[image]

Which results in an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

If you remove those, the code works fine:

```js
$("<option>", { value: '', selected: true }).prependTo("#theSelectId");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="theSelectId">
    <option selected="selected" value=""/>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/) method append element at the beginning. To append after an element use [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method.

```js
// get all options were value is not empty
$('#theSelectId option:not([value=""])')
  // append empty option after the element
  .after('<option value=""></option>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="theSelectId">
  <option selected="selected" value="" />
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, Exactly i need this. Working properly. :)